How to avoid the "Unknown column" error in Sequelize (MySQL)
How to avoid the "Unknown column" error in Sequelize (MySQL) when a field is missing in the database and return NULL instead of an error in production?
I am working with Sequelize and MySQL, and I am encountering an issue when executing a query that uses a field that was manually removed from the database. In the development environment, this error seems logical, but in the production environment, I would like to avoid the error and instead return NULL in places where the field no longer exists in the table.
ORM CALL :    const fillials = await FilialDBModel.findAll();
EXECUTED SQL :
SELECT `ID`, `free_delivery_sum`, `other_field` FROM `s4y_fillials`;

The field free_delivery_sum was removed, and the query throws the error
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'free_delivery_sum' in 'field list'
How can I:
Prevent Sequelize from throwing an error when the field is missing in the database.
Return NULL instead of throwing an error in the production environment when the field is absent.
Avoid changes to the database (such as re-adding the field to the schema).
For example i want the orm to return some like "{ID:1,free_delivery_sum:null,other_field:"some_data"}"

I see two possible ways: 1. try to get the actual list of columns using a special raw query to find out what fields are actually there and turn such fields into virtual ones 2. Create a migration (if you use them) that deletes this column (that was already removed manually) and add the name of migration to the applied migrations table manually

You should change the model in Sequelize to match the change to the database.

@Anatoly "get the actual list of columns" maybe is any options in sequlize to sync model with database?seems like that common orm operation should include. I find in docs sync option,but this one is another. I dont want sequlize modify my database.

Usual way is to modify a model and create a migration that reflects this change. If you have migrations auto-applied on the new app version deployment then you will have consistent and matching DB structure and models in the app
